# Why is react conflicted between different base.js files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, web3js

### Context

I'm following the [web3.js guide](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js) on how to use web3.js with create-react-app. The setup seems clear. I installed the missing modules via npm, created the `config-overrides.js` file in my project root and made the adjustments, but I'm now having issues.

### Problem

I can use the web3 library just fine, but react throws this error:

[image]

First off, It's worth noting that a similar post to fix this same error exists, claiming it is a case error in the file path that is Windows specific. As far as I cant tell, **this problem is different!** I'm on Mac, and I cannot find the case discrepancies that post mentions.

Now I've tried a few things to resolve this. First, I followed another post that recommended I uninstall the eslint extension (I'm using Atom). **This actually worked for about 10 minutes**, but then the same error reappeared after I created a few components.

Then, I noticed that the error points to two `node_modules` folders, one outside of my create-react-app project folder along with the normal one inside. And oddly enough, I do have a `node_modules` outside the project folder, complete with a package and package-lock json files:

[image]

I changed the name of each folder to see if one of them was redundant and could be deleted, but react threw the same compile errors if one of the `node_modules` wasn't found.

At this point, I'm in over my head. I have no idea where that folder came from or why react placed it there. I'm not sure how to resolve the two `node_modules` and thus the conflict between the base.js files. It might be worth noting that the two `node_modules` folders have different module contents. The one *outside* the project folder holds no web3 modules, while the folder *inside* does.

Looking at the folder's get info shows that it was created at 10:43am, about the same time I was following the guide I mentioned first. I hope this post was clear. If not, I'll happily provide any extra info. Thanks.